# importing image sequence into 3ds max

Tags: 3dsmax, autodesk, 3ds

i'm trying to import an image sequence onto a plane as a texture, i've imported the 1st picture of the image sequence and ticked the sequence option but it does not run through the sequence, any suggestions please or have I done something wrong? Online results have said i can just import the original video as a texture onto a plane but that does not work either, any help much appreciated!

Comment: What name does your texture files have?

Comment: vlcsnap-2014-02-13-00h54m28s136, thats the name of the 1st image in the image sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the images to be ending with a sequential number.
For example:

> vlcsnap-2014-02-13-00h54m28s136_0001.bmp
>
> vlcsnap-2014-02-13-00h54m28s136_0002.bmp

When you then select the first image 3dsmax will detect that they are sequential and will create a ascii file with all the file names, which it then uses to read in all the files sequentially when it's applied as texture.

If you have a lot of images already, then you can easily batch-rename them with freely available software.

Comment: thank you for replying! vlcsnap-2014-02-13-00h54m28s136_bmp0001001, thats the new name i gave the images in the batch rename, each has an increment of 1, I applied the texture but it still does not play through as a sequence in 3ds max

Comment: I tested it now, I named my bitmaps:
a_0001
a_0002
a_0003

when browsing to the 'bitmap'when assigning it to diffuse slot - make sure you check the 'sequence' then you select your bitmap.

Comment: did it exactly how you did it, it worked! thank you!

Comment: Great.

remember to mark the answer, so that people who answer get's their points, and makes it easier for others to see that it's been already answered properly.

Comment: no problem, think i marked it by "ticking" the answer. thanks again